# How to connect to SQL Server from command prompt with Windows authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, command-prompt

How can I connect to SQL Server from command prompt using Windows authentication?

This command

```
Sqlcmd -u username -p password
```

assumes a username & password for the SQL Server already setup

Alternatively how can I setup a user account from command prompt?

I've SQL Server 2008 Express on a Windows Server 2008 machine, if that relates.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use different syntax to achieve different things. If it is windows authentication you want, you could try this:

```
sqlcmd /S  /d  -E
```

If you want to use SQL Server authentication you could try this:

```
sqlcmd /S  /d -U -P
```

Definitions:

```
/S = the servername/instance name. Example: Pete's Laptop/SQLSERV
/d = the database name. Example: Botlek1
-E = Windows authentication.
-U = SQL Server authentication/user. Example: Pete
-P = password that belongs to the user. Example: 1234
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Try This :

--Default Instance

```
SQLCMD -S SERVERNAME -E
```

--OR 
--Named Instance

```
SQLCMD -S SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME -E
```

--OR

```
SQLCMD -S SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME,1919 -E
```

More details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191518.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This might help..!!!

```
 SQLCMD -S SERVERNAME -E
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Vipin Mittal already mention this- not working :(

Comment: [Click the link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2478/connecting-to-sql-server-using-sqlcmd-utility/) I got that from here,see whether the link is helpfull to u..!!!

Comment: If I see one more person say "not working"........ **EXPLAIN**. What is not working? Are you getting a message? Whats the message?

Answer (score 0):

After some tries, these are the samples I am using in order to connect:

Specifying the username and the password:

```
sqlcmd -S 211.11.111.111 -U NotSA -P NotTheSaPassword
```

Specifying the DB as well:

```
sqlcmd -S 211.11.111.111 -d SomeSpecificDatabase -U NotSA -P NotTheSaPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

type sqlplus/"as sysdba" in cmd
for connection in cmd prompt

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I thought that `sqlplus` is an SQL client for an Oracle DB?

Comment: sqlplus is ORACLEDB utility not SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

here is the commend which is tested 
Sqlcmd -E -S "server name" -d "DB name" -i "SQL file path"

-E stand for windows trusted

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Linux, Mac OS or Windows, you can use MSSQL-CLI. Read the tutorial at https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5298/new-interactive-command-line-tool-mssqlcli-for-sql-server/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30953334)

Answer (score 0):

With either of **2 commands below**, I could log in **SQL Server 2019 Express** through **Windows authentication**:

```
sqlcmd -S DESKTOP-5K4TURF\SQLEXPRESS -E
```

```
sqlcmd /S DESKTOP-5K4TURF\SQLEXPRESS /E
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can connect easily:

1. sqlcmd -S `Your Server Name` -U 'Login username'-P 'password'
2. Type command: `select name from sys.database` and will show `>1` in next line
   means database server connected
3. Type `go` and pres enter will list all database(s)
4. You can select any particular one and can go ahead

Comment: you omit the 's' at the end of sys.databases